# \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb} problem

Tags: errors

```
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
Undefined control sequence. \end{align*}
```

But

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb}
```

Load

Comment: the format  you show is not the format TeX uses for error messages. Please show the exact lines from the log file, and also a small test document that produces the error.

Comment: I would guess that the full error messages shows some undefined command and `\end{align*}` is shown as the point at which TeX detected the error. But unless you show which command was undefined it is hard to suggest any fix.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 5):

TeX error messages have a multi-line structure that indicates the nature of the error and the point that TeX had reached in the source file (which may be later than the actual error).

Given

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  a&=b\\
  a\Zzzzzz&=foo\\
  x&=y
\end{align*}
\end{document
```

then the terminal shows:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument>  a&=b\\ a\Zzzzzz 
                            &=foo\\ x&=y 
l.11 \end{align*}

? h
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

?
```

So here the undefined command is indicated by the linebreak and is `\Zzzzzz`
TeX had grabbed the entire alignment before processing its content so it had reached line 11 with `\end{align*}` before the error is detected, which is indicated by the final line of the error message showing

```
l.11 \end{align*}
```

So the fix is either to define `\Zzzzzz` if it should be there or delete it if it should not be there.